# Invalid name for salesforce subtab

Tags: javascript, service-cloud-console

On trying to override an existing subtab on click of a button in vf page, I am getting invalid name for subtab error.

```
var stabid = '';

function edit(){
sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(opensubtab);
}
var opensubtab = function opensubtab(result){
var primID = result.id;
sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(closesubtab);
sforce.console.openSubtab(primId,'/apex/TESTPAGE',true,'salesforce',stabid,opensuccess,'salesforceSubtab');
};
var closesubtab = function closesubtab(result){
stabid = result.id;
}
```

Method getting called on click of button.

Answer (score 0):

This [openSubtab()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_opensubtab.htm) documentation says:

> ID of the subtab to override. Use null to create a new subtab.

but you are passing in just an empty string:

```
var stabid= '';
```

I see there are multiple methods such as `getFocusedSubtabId()` to find a valid value to pass in.

Comment: The callback method closesubtab is used to fetch the subtabID , which is then passed into the openSubtab method. Shouldn't the callback execute before openSubtab is executed

Comment: @starhunter Oh I see better now. Unfortunately the `getEnclosingTabId` method is documented as being asynchronous so the callback may well be called after the `openSubtab` call is made. You could add some `console.log` calls to check the ordering. Generally where a callback is present in JavaScript that callback code gets run out in the future.